# geofence pending intent returns

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, geofencing, android-geofence

I am hoping to add functionality to my application that allows me to use the ID of a triggered Geofence to select a corresponding sample(url) from an array which can then be passed to an exoplayer for streaming.

Currently I am following the geofencing api which uses a pending intent hooked up to an intentservice to manage geofence transitions etc etc.

Looking at the pending intent which is set up in the main activity can I request it to return the geofence ID upon transition? 
I am very new to both android and this api so any and all help would be really appreciated!
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (which I may not), the Geofence ID should already be being returned when the transition event occurs.

Paraphrasing the documentation, when your PendingIntent is triggered:

> You can call `GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(Intent)` to get the transition type, geofences
>   that triggered this intent and the location that triggered the
>   geofence transition.

From the resulting [GeofencingEvent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingEvent) object, you can call `getTriggeringGeofences()` to retrieve the list of `Geofence`'s that caused the transition, and then `getRequestId()` on each one to retrieve the ID.

**Edit**
Some code... this is untested (since I refuse to dance about testing Geofence boundaries!), but I'm hoping it should work.
I'm assuming you already have a working Geofence setup and that it is calling your IntentService correctly. In your IntentService, you should have an onHandleIntent method:

```
void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // retrieve the GeofencingEvent from the passed Intent
    GeofencingEvent ge = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

    // get the Geofences that triggered it
    List<Geofence> fences = ge.getTriggeringGeofences();

    // checking there is only one fence (bad assumption!!!!), retrieve the request Id
    if (fences == null || fences.size() != 1) {
        return;
    }
    String fenceID = fences.get(0).getRequestId();

    // do something funky with it...
}
```

You should debug or log each line to check it's working properly. Let me know if this doesn't work or wasn't what you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much this is definitely a step in the right direction for me! This seems like exactly what I need to accomplish. My idea is that I can get the Id of the triggered geofence and then use that to send a corresponding url to my exoplayer instance and begin an audio stream. This has been very difficult for me to get my head around so I really appreciate your help! I'm still not sure how to achieve what I'm looking to do but you have definitely given me a step in the right direction so thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having trouble trying to implement the advice you have given to me. I am very much an amateur at this I'm afraid :( 

If you or perhaps anyone reading this have any time to be able help me further with this problem it would be much appreciated as I am having troubles with knowing where to put these elements in my code and how to use them properly :S 

Thank you so much for your help already and any future help!

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! 
I haven't gone through everything yet but I am overwhelmed by your kindness this problem has been such a bugbear for me for the past couple days! 
If I could buy you a beer I would! 
Hopefully this will be the key to end my woes :)! 
cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your patience so far! This is the setup I am trying :) It probably is completely wrong! The log o/p is Home so that is nice however my intent doesn't start, is this not possible from within this service? should i broadcast message instead or is there a smarter method? Again I owe you a lot already so thank you if you can help me more as well!
         if (fenceID == Home){
Intent mpdIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class)
.setData(Uri.parse("http://maxmarshall.ddns.net/segments/TEST_dash.mpd"))
.putExtra(PlayerActivity.CONTENT_ID_EXTRA, "my test")
startActivity(mpdIntent);
}

Comment: What you've described should work - it is possible to launch an activity from a service. I think you need the new_task flag set before you call startActivity(). e.g mpdIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);, but without seeing the code, it's hard to determine why it's failing. Looking at the output of logcat might give you a clue, or you can just post another question on SO!

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help these past couple days you have been great! For now I am heading in the right direction with things so I really appreciate everything!